# adjusting quotationmarks in big text with PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a big text with different combinations of quotationmarks and many sentences.
Example:

```
This is the „LIFE IS A JOKE“ T-Shirt.

There are different kind of „JOKES".

Text text "LIFE IS A JOKE“ you see text.

Last example is "LIFE IS A JOKE" ok.
```

The output of all quotation appearance should be like in the first example with `„ ... “`.

How would you do this?

Like, count the number of different types of marks and replace it according to (is_even_number of mark or not). I am not directly asking for code in this question, I ask for logic assistance and a little hint..

Answer (score 0):

You could count them, but then if there is a missing quote somewhere they'll be bad from that point on.

I'd look at the relative position of the quote. Is like: `"abc` or `abc"`.

Something like:

```
preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z])\"/", "\\1“")
preg_replace("/\"([a-zA-Z])/", "„\\1")
```